# Cordova app is killed/crashed after few days(5-7 days)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

My Cordova android app (a kind of kiosk app) which has to run continuously is killed/crashed after few days of usage.

**Plugins used:**

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^6.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="com.cordova.plugins.cookiemaster" spec="~1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^5.0.2">
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-awesome-shared-preferences" spec="^0.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^6.0.3" />
    <plugin name="sentry-cordova" spec="^0.17.0" />
```

Tried android memory profiling as well but did not get any memory leakage but noticed a continuous increase of memory over time.

**Any suggestions, how can i fix this crash/kill after few days?**

Tried to handle uncaught exception and restart the app when it crashes but no luck

```
 public static final String TAG = "uncaughtException";

  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
    if (myContext != null) {
      PackageManager pm = myContext.getPackageManager();
      if (pm != null) {
        Intent mStartActivity = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(
          myContext.getPackageName()
        );
        if (mStartActivity != null) {
          mStartActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
          myContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(mStartActivity);
          Log.i(TAG, "Killing application for cold restart");
          //kill the application
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```